# how to get single data value from Multiple data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at jQuery Problem. i think i am going wrong in this code. please help.

I'm trying to get value of input box by clicking update button. but everytime i get only first number.

I want text value according update button.

```js
$(".update").click(function(){
    qty = $(".qty").val();  
    alert(qty);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="5" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="20" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="30" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="50" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="45" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="15" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="70" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
        <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to "link" your update button whith the input ".qty" you want to associate to

```js
$(".update").click(function(){
 qty = $(this).closest("tr").find(".qty").val(); 
 alert(qty);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="5" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="20" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="30" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="50" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="45" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="15" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="70" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

change the qty variable as below:
var thisObj = $(this);
qty = $(thisObj).parent().parent().find("input").val();

```js
$(".update").click(function(){
 qty = $(".qty").val(); 
 alert(qty);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="5" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="20" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="30" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="50" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="45" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="15" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="70" class="qty" id="qty"/></td>
  <td><button class="update">&#x21BB;</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your example snippet is still having the old behavior